# 100 Amp sub panel 240 ft away from main panel

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, aluminum-wiring

I'm adding a sub panel to a workshop building which will require 240 ft of wire. To keep costs down I plan to run aluminum. Can someone please confirm my plan is adequate for the situation.
[image]

1. Code does not allow AL in main panel except for service wire. Plan to convert AL to CU in junction box and then connect to main panel 100amp breaker (see A -> M) (sensible?)
2. Is 3/0 AL overkill for 100 amp sub panel
3. Should garage have a separate grounding rod?
4. What should I use to connect AL to CU in (A)?
5. For (B) does an AL to CU disconnect exist?

Other notes:
I plan to run 3 AL and 1 8 AWG cables under ground in a 2 inch SCH 80 PVC - Is that advisable?

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Can you post a link to the local electrical code amendments in your jurisdiction? That's the only way I can see that aluminum wire would somehow be forbidden in the main panel outside of service wiring...

Comment: Also, how many square feet is your shop, and what do you plan to use there for tools?

Answer (score 4):

> Code does not allow AL in main panel except for service wire.

That is incorrect in almost all places that use AWG for wire and inches for conduit size.  Even the bonkers Montgomery *County* Maryland allows aluminum 2 AWG and larger.  There is nothing wrong with aluminum; that is superstition due to a totally unrelated incident with a hasty attempt to use transmission-line-grade aluminum for small branch circuit wiring. There is no history of failures in aluminum heavy feeder, which is landed on terminals rated for aluminum and torqued to spec.  This is either a misunderstanding, or an inspector whose brother sells copper wire.

> Is 3/0 AL overkill for 100 amp sub panel

Very much so, as is the copper size you specified. It sounds like you are pulling numbers out of the wrong codebook, or misusing that book, or are not doing voltage drop calculations correctly.  Normally I would say "It's your money, have fun" but there's a practical showstopper: those sizes of wires will not fit on 100A breakers or panel lugs on 100A panels. (the latter is easily fixed by using larger rated panels, of course; and that would be a good thing.)  But it would be better to fix the underlying error.

> What should I use to connect AL to CU in (A)?

Polaris connectors and a very large junction box/gutter to provide necessary wire bending space. None of that is cheap.

### Start by re-assessing demand and voltage drop

Honestly, 99% of the time when someone picks 100A subpanel, that number is picked from some source *other than* what their expected loads actually are. It might be too little but most often it's more than they need.   For instance it's often because the subpanel *is rated* 100A. Go look at your car's tires, I bet they say something like 112 MPH speed rating". That's just a "never exceed" redline, ***not a suggestion!***  The same is true for subpanels; a 100A subpanel is at redline at 100A; they're not saying "run a 100A feeder to this", just "it's not unsafe if you do".

We also strongly recommend subpanels with *lots of spaces*, and that (and being sensible with feeder wire cost) usually means de-coupling "subpanel size (bus rating or main breaker)" from "feeder size".  So focus on *plenty of spaces and then some*, and that will dictate a main breaker and bus rating, and just have your feeder be <= that.

Oh, and people get hung up on "I want the subpanel breaker to be the same size as the feed breaker *so it trips first and I don't have to walk 240 feet*".  That plan never works, for a variety of reasons.

Now as far as voltage drop, people get these calculations wrong *a lot*.  To start with, voltage drop can't read, so it doesn't know the amp number on the handle of the supply breaker.  Voltage drop only responds to *actual load* - which if you are following the rules won't be more than 80% of breaker trip.  Also, depending on the loads you're driving, "3% voltage drop" is wire salesman's nonsense.

- For a 120/240V feeder, give '240V' as the voltage
- For percentage drop, override it and put 6% and see what number you get.  You can turn it down later.
- For amps, use the actual load you are going to have, *never breaker trip* - and certainly never more than 80% of breaker trip.

At 240V I don't even bother thinking about voltage drop until at least 170 feet, so you only need one wire size bump at the absolute outside... unless your collective loads will be *very heavily* loading the feeder  and you have calculated the loads and determined that paying for thicker wire is a net win compared with accepting another 0.8% voltage drop.

So we need to go back to your *actual loads* and a NEC Article 220 Load Calculation on the workshop.  Note that in a typical home workshop, only one tool at a time is operated, except that compressor and dust collector are added, as is light and HVAC loads.  HVAC should be a "mini-split heat pump"; don't waste money on those gimpy toaster heaters unless you plan to heat the workshop *very occasionally*. Not least, they don't give you A/C.

### Sizing the wire, though

As discussed above, I wouldn't even bother doing a voltage drop calculation if your distance was 30% less.  So you need *at most* one size of voltage drop bump, if that.   Also, unless you are in Canada or a few other odd jurisdictions, you can ignore voltage drop when choosing the breaker. NEC simply allows you to endure the voltage drop if you do't mind.

My "go-to" just because of its general availability is #2 aluminum, which is 90A nominally and can be breakered at 90A (though you will exceed 3% drop if you actually pull 72A on it; but you will do this rarely if ever, unless your shop is unusual).

- So most normal workshops will almost never exceed 65A and #2Al is perfect at your distance, breakered at 90A.
- If your actual calculated load is maybe up to 80A, then #1Al on 100A breaker.
- Other than that, I'd consider 1/0 Al to be adequate, though it may be more readily available as 2/0.  The problem is, 2/0 isn't going to fit on a 100A breaker.  One answer is go go up to a 125A breaker for 2/0.

2" conduit is larger than is required for sensibly sized wire. However no one ever regretted putting it in - it makes pulling easier.

### Enlarging conductors? Enlarge ground in proportion!

For 100A, 1 AWG aluminum is adequate. You propose to enlarge 3 sizes larger than is necessary.  That will require a proportionate enlargement of the ground wire.  Since #5 copper ground does not exist, you will need #4 copper or #2 insulated aluminum.

If the garage is detached, then it needs local grounding rods, bonded to the ground wire but not the neutral. These do a different job than the ground wires and both are required.

### Understanding disconnects

People often misunderstand the disconnect requirement for a subpanel in an outbuilding.  It is not required to be outdoors.   It is not required to be *a separate physical thing* than the breaker panel.  It is not forbidden from being a breaker.

The most cost-effective way to meet this requirement is choose a subpanel *which has a main breaker*. This is what almost everyone does.  The main breaker serves as the disconnect.  This works because of the odd "economies of scale" of mass-produced panels - breakers are cheaper than switches sometimes.  The breaker functionality is completely superfluous and is not used.

Comment: *bonkers Montgomery County Maryland* Ah, but there's no place like home :-)

Comment: Harper, are you *in* MoCo?

Comment: @Huesmann not me, I'd have trouble under a flag that on a 0-10 scale [actually rolls over](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4w6808wJcU) 12:30 :)